# Not able to add elements to an array in typescript using chart.js and bootstrat charts

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have a odd issue. I have a simple function with a map that attempted to initialize an array of the same object type. However it is empty after the iteration is complete but when I console log it is prints all of the array of objects.

function in component

object:

```
dailyStats: DailyStats[] = [];
```

-- function

```
dailyStatistics() {
        this.reportingService.dailyStats(this.toDate, this.fromDate).subscribe( r => {
            r.map(res => this.dailyStats.push(res)); //console log prints the whole array all of them!
        },
       error => {
            console.log('Failed to get Stats' + error);
        },
        () => {
            console.log('Done getting daily stats.');
        });
    }
```

---

```
showDailyStats() {
        console.log('length' + this.dailyStats.length);  // length 0
        for (const value of this.dailyStats) {
            console.log('average' + value.average);
            //this.lineChartLabels.push(value.date.toISOString());
            //this.lineChartData.push({ data: [value.average], label: 'Average' });
        }

    }
```

Comment: What do you really want to do ? Do you want to push all the elements from response into array dailyStats ?? I just don't understand the structure of data returned from response, and what you want to do ?

Comment: Are you sure that `showDailyStats` is executing after `dailyStats` is populated?

Comment: You're misusing the `map` here: `r.map(res => this.dailyStats.push(res));`. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the method showDailyStats after the dailyStatistics you have to use async/await to wait for the data to come into the array before accessing its content.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign result of asynchronous call directly in `subscribe` without using `map` method and then call your method `showDailyStats`:

```
.subscribe( r => {
    this.dailyStats = r; //console log prints the whole array all of them!
    this.showDailyStats();
}
```